# Cumulative sum by category in time series data in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make this data frame into a dictionary so I can create a plot in matplotlib. My solution is the following, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way.

```
    import datetime as dt
    import pandas as pd
     
    today = dt.date.today()
    monday = today - dt.timedelta(days=today.weekday(), weeks=1)
    date_range = pd.Series(monday + dt.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(5))
    date_range1 = pd.DataFrame({"create_date":pd.to_datetime(date_range)})

    countries = list(df['country'].unique())
    dic = {}
    for country in countries:
        lst = df[df.country == country]
        sub = date_range1.merge(lst, on='create_date', how='outer')
        dic[country] = list(sub['frequency'].fillna(0).cumsum())
```

DataFrame

```
   create_date country  frequency
0   2020-08-24      AU        9.0
1   2020-08-24      CN        3.0
2   2020-08-24      FJ        1.0
3   2020-08-25      CN        3.0
4   2020-08-25      ID        2.0
5   2020-08-26      ID        1.0
6   2020-08-27     NaN        NaN
```

Result

```
{
'AU': [9, 9, 9, 9],
'CN': [3, 6, 6, 6],
'FJ': [1, 1, 1, 1],
'ID': [0, 2, 3, 3]
}
```

Comment: Why can you not just `df.plot()`? See the user guide section on [visualization](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html#visualization)

Comment: The condition is how to reshape the data frame, not about which package I need to use.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.pivot`:

```
df2 = df.pivot("create_date", "country", "frequency").fillna(0).cumsum()
df2[df2.columns.dropna()].to_dict("list")
```

Output:

```
{'AU': [9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0],
 'CN': [3.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0],
 'FJ': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
 'ID': [0.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0]}
```